# Disable form submit button outside the form in Vue Formulate

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js, vue-formulate

I have a very simple form like this:

```
<FormulateForm
  #default="{ hasErrors }"
  @submit="submitHandler"
>
  <FormulateInput
    type="email"
    label="Please enter a superhero email address"
    validation="required|email"
  />
  <FormulateInput
    type="checkbox"
    label="Select some of your favorite superheros"
    validation="required|min:2"
    :options="{
      batman: 'Batman',
      blackpanther: 'Black Panther'
      wonderwoman: 'Wonder woman',
    }"
  />
</FormulateForm>

<div>
  <FormulateInput
    type="submit"
    :disabled="hasErrors"
  />
</div>

methods: {
  submitHandler() {
    alert('Thank you')
  },
}
```

How do I disable the form submit button which is outside the form using Vue Formulate when the validation is failing?